# Why can't mongodb `indexStats` command be used in production?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Mongodb [documentation on the `indexStats` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/indexStats/) states :

> Warning : This command is not intended for production deployments.

but no reason is given. I would like to understand the reasons since I would like to use it on my production deployment.

Is it because it is experimental ? (as the required `--enableExperimentalIndexStatsCmd` would suggest) --> the risk may be acceptable

Or is it because it's detrimental to performance ? --> Most likely not worth it.

Or is it for another reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [here](https://github.com/utaal/mongovis#overview):

> Both commands take a global READ_LOCK and will page in all the extents
>   or btree buckets encountered: this will have adverse effects on server
>   performance. The commands should never be run on a primary and will
>   cause a secondary to fall behind on replication.

Also experimental features are not thoroughly tested and therefore it is not advisable to run anything experimental in production.